# How to load images to imageView from URL, sequentially rather than collectively?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, imageurl

I am trying to load a couple images from a URL to my `imageView` but the way my code is set up, the app waits for the entire set of images to be downloaded and only then are the images displayed to the user. This causes a massive amount of waiting time once the application is opened.

To remove the waiting time, the images must be loaded to the `imageView` as soon as they are downloaded from the webURL, one by one.
Could someone suggest how to do this?

Here is my code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource {    

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let imageFetcher = ImageFetcher()

    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageFetcher.setImageURL()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(01, target: self, selector: #selector(addCells), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func addCells(timer : NSTimer){

        if(counter == imageFetcher.ImageArray.count){
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }

        counter = counter + 1

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: counter-1 , inSection: 0)
        collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("numberOfItemsInSection method just ran")                                                    //timeline indicator
        return counter    
    }      

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView.image = imageFetcher.ImageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

**ImageFetcher.swift**

```
class ImageFetcher {

    var newImage : UIImage?
    var ImageArray = [UIImage]()
    var imageURL : NSURL?{
        didSet{  newImage = nil
            Adder()
        }
    }

    func setImageURL(){
        imageURL = DemoURLs.randomImageUrl
    }    

    func fetchImage() {
        if let url = imageURL{
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            if imageData != nil{
                self.newImage  = UIImage( data: imageData! )
            } else {
                self.newImage = nil

            }
        }
    }

    func Adder(){
        for _ in 1...20 {

            fetchImage()
            ImageArray.append(newImage!)

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should be fetching images asynchronously (using `NSURLSession`) rather than synchronously (using `NSData(contentsOfURL:)`), and then in the completion handler, updating the UI as appropriate. Or, even better, find a `UIImageView` extension that supports asynchronous image retrieval, such as [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) or [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift/27712427#27712427

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the image when the cell is being displayed.

**ImageFetcher.swift**

```
class ImageFetcher {
    var images:[NSIndexPath: UIImage] = [:]
    func downloadImage(completion: (UIImage?)->Void) {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        if let url = self.imageURL {
            let imageURL = NSURL(string: url)

            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: imageURL!)

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {data, response, downloadError in

                if let imageData = data, image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    completion(image)
                } else {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            } 
            task.resume()
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }

    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

   cell.imageView.image = nil //or the placeholder image

   if let img = imageFetcher.images.valueForKey[indexPath] {
      cell.imageView.image = img
   } else {
      imageFetcher.downloadImage({ (image) in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if let img = image {
                    let c = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
                    c.imageView.image = img
                    imageFetcher.images[indexPath] = img
                } else {
                    print("Error!")
                }
            })

        })
   }


   return cell
}
```